# Проблема с циклом. python

Tags: python

Ввожу количество повторов `d`, а он вне зависимости от введенного числа делает только 2 повтора.

```
def price(a):
    if a > 1000:
        a -= a / 100 * 10
        print('%.2f' % a)
    else:
        print('%.2f' % a)


d = int(input())
print(d)
for i in [0, d]:
    a = int(input())
    price(a)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код (кнопка `править`)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Если ```a -= a / 100 * 10``` является расчетом десятипроцентной скидки, не проще ли сократить запись до ```a -= a / 10```, а функцию как таковую представить как ```price = lambda a: print('%.2f' % (a - a / 10 if a > 1000 else a))```?!

Answer (score 2):

Нужно написать так

```
for i in range(d):
```

вместо

```
for i in [0, d]
```

Answer (score 2):

Как было уже сказано, цикл нужно организовать следующим образом:

```
for i in range(d):
```

---

И небольшая ремарка относительно оптимизации длинны кода.
В теле функции достаточно было указать:

```
if a > 1000:
        a -= a / 100 * 10
print('%.2f' % a)
```

вместо:

```
if a > 1000:
    a -= a / 100 * 10
    print('%.2f' % a)
else:
    print('%.2f' % a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы неверно записали цикл.
Строку с for  замените на:

```
for i in range(d):
```

Ваш вариант перебирает два элеиента скписка  [0,d]